# Deploying rails app to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deployed my app to heroku. Everything was ok. When i go to the rails app, sometimes, i.e at some links it crashes. The error message says (We are sorry but something went wrong.Checking error logs i found:

```html
SELECT "staffs".* FROM "staffs"  ORDER BY "staffs"."name" ASC
2015-03-31T06:41:33.006245+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "staffs" does not exist
```

And i am sure i have migration that creates my staffs table. My app works fine in development but in production i have such problems. (i use sqlite in development and PG in production.
What can be causing such problems?
Here is my migration for staffs:

```html
class CreateStaffs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :staffs do |t|
 t.string :name, null:false
 t.string :responsibility
        t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: have you executed `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: Definitely you didn't migrate your db yet. Run the above command in terminal. And check the log by command ``heroku logs --tails``

Comment: @duykhoa yep, i run that command. the problem was that i had to run setup command before migration. i don't know why. tutorials did't say that.  but running db:setup fixed my problem.

Comment: Did you change the migration files?

Comment: @duykhoa no, i just run db:setup before migrating and then migrated again. That solved my problem.